# Share data between C++ and C# or VB (2 running program)

Tags: c#, c++, ipc

is there a way (other than network(i hate io-streams)) to communicate between 2 process? one in c++ and other one in C# or VB.
my problem is, im writing a AVR program using c++, but for debugging purpose i need a GUI to test different inputs. since i donno anything about GUI in c++ ( and i have no plan to learn it), i want to write the GUI using .net and somehow connect it to my c++ code.
since i have 2 running process i cant use p/invoke and other similar methods. If i could share my variables between 2 process or call a function in c# from c++ (from running process to running process), that would solve my problem.
anything other than sockets?

Comment: The best I can think of without sockets would be running one process from the other, with some startup arguments

Comment: Is it just for debugging and testing or you need real world solution ?

Comment: nope, its just for debugging and testing, so i dont mind dirty solutions. and since its temporary, just need a quick fast way..., using ram. my HDD is not feeling well as it is :cry:

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned .NET you probably on MS Windows. You may use DDE (Dynamic Data Exchange):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648774(v=vs.85).aspx

You can find .NET tutorial for it here:

http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2009/06/10/DDE-in-NET.aspx

---

If you want fast dummy solution that will work for you just for debugging not as real solution. You may share your data by writing them to the hard disk and reading it from it again. It is not hard neither complicated.

Comment: since im gonna check that data rapidly (at least 10 time every sec), i guss filesystem is not a good solution, i`m reading about DDE, tnx

Answer (score 0):

What about databases? if you are using MS you can try MSSQL.

Its absolutely free for small databases i think :)